# How to get number of specific line in multi line text box after loop check in vb .net?

Tags: vb.net, foreach, textbox

I have a multi-line text box that contains a number of blank lines and I want to check these blank lines by loop and then give me the number of that blank line.

```
        For Each line As String In TextBox2.Lines

            If line = "" Then

             'line.linenumber
           
            End If

        Next
```

Comment: If you want to work with an index then it should be obvious that you need to use a `For` loop rather than a `For Each` loop. That said, there's no need for a loop at all, because you can simply call `Array.IndexOf` to get the first index of an empty `String` in the array.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Dear jmcilhinney, as always, the answer is short and effective. thank you so much, This is exactly what I wanted.